# Meaning of @ sign in Makefile? (Not echo suppression nor automatic variable)

Tags: makefile

What does the `@` sign inside of the substitution reference in this Makefile recipe mean? I know it's not echo suppression and I'm fairly confident it's not an automatic variable (at least one that I know of).

I've tried replacing the `@` sign with `$@`, as basically what the substitution reference is supposed to do is to simply replace the suffix of the target from `.d` to `.o`, but this seems to output an empty string. In it's current state with just `@` it works perfectly (but I want to know why).

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.d: %.cpp | $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MM -MT $(@:.d=.o) $< > $@
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$@` is an automatic variable, see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables

> The file name of the target of the rule.

As far as the behavior caused by prepending `$` to `@`, that's how variables work in make, see https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html#SEC58

> To substitute a variable's value, write a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable in parentheses or braces: either `$(foo)` or `${foo}` is a valid reference to the variable foo. This special significance of `$` is why you must write `$$` to have the effect of a single dollar sign in a file name or command.

You can test this with an example:

```
SOMEVAR:=hello

test:
    echo ${SOMEVAR}
    echo $SOMEVAR
    echo $(SOMEVAR:hello=world)
    echo $($SOMEVAR:hello=world)
```

The behavior (echo output omitted) is:

```
echo hello
echo OMEVAR
echo world
echo
```

As you can see the last result is blank because make tries to resolve the `OMEVAR` variable, which is unset.

Comment: In addition, please review the syntax for substitution references: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html